# defaultValue not woking on CheckboxGroupInput

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm trying to write a simple check box group like this:

```
<CheckboxGroupInput source="test" defaultValue={{ _id: 123 }} choices={[
    { _id: 123, name: 'Leo Tolstoi', sex: 'M' },
    { _id: 456, name: 'Jane Austen', sex: 'F' },
  ]} />
```

I couldnt find an example of how to specify the defaultValue for CheckboxGroupInput.
i also tried passing:

```
defaultValue={{ _id: 123, name: 'Leo Tolstoi', sex: 'M', checked: true }}
defaultValue={[{ _id: 123, name: 'Leo Tolstoi', sex: 'M', checked: true }]}
defaultValue="123"
```

any leads are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the `optionValue` prop to `_id`. The default is `id`. See the documentation: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#checkboxgroupinput

Comment: thanks @Gildas i added the optionValue but still not change

Comment: Can you update your code or, even better, set up a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/5xwv91v4n4) ?

Comment: By the way, what version are you using ?